# How to override type of element inherited from parent complex type?

Tags: java, xml, inheritance, xsd, jaxb

I do code generation from XSD (using JAXB). I have one superclass and several subclasses. One of the superclass' properties (let's say, `prop`) has type `A`. I also have types `B extends A` and `C extends A` (defined in XSD). The superclass' schema defines an element of type `A`, which is inherited by the subclasses. I want to use types `B` and `C` instead of `A` in the subclasses.

```
<xsd:complexType name="Superclass">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="prop" type="A" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="Subclass1">
    <xsd:complexContent>
        <xsd:extension base="Superclass"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="someAttribute" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="Subclass2">
    <xsd:complexContent>
        <xsd:extension base="Superclass"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="someOtherAttribute" type="xsd:int"/>
    </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
```

The generated `Superclass.java` will have `List<A> prop`. For example, I want the `prop` to be overriden with type `List<B>` in the `Subclass1.java` and with `List<C>` in `Subclass2.java`. The primary goal is to have the `prop` in the superclass, but to use other (compatible) types in the subclasses.

Comment: I am not sure what the expected code is for subclasses ? A new `prop` attribute definition ? Or one unique `prop` in `Superclass` ?

Comment: Override is for methods only!

Answer (score 1):

I find no samples, where xsd elements(/complex types) are extended & overridden like that, but you can do it, when `Subclass1` and `Subclass2` (and `Superclass`) reside in different "definitions". You would `xs:override`  `Superclass` in both of the "sub-xsds" (one with B and one with C type), and then extend them accordingly:

parent.xsd:

```
<xsd:complexType name="Superclass">
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="prop" type="A" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

sub1.xsd:

```
<xs:override schemaLocation="parent.xsd">
  <xsd:complexType name="Superclass">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="prop" type="B" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xs:override>
<!-- and just : -->
<xsd:complexType name="Subclass1">
  <xsd:complexContent>
    <xsd:extension base="Superclass"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="someAttribute" type="xsd:string"/>
  </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
```

and sub2.xsd:

```
<xs:override schemaLocation="parent.xsd">
  <xsd:complexType name="Superclass">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="prop" type="C" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xs:override>
<xsd:complexType name="Subclass2">
 <xsd:complexContent>
   <xsd:extension base="Superclass"/>
   <xsd:attribute name="someOtherAttribute" type="xsd:int"/>
 </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
```

It must be in different definitions, because I don't know how to overcome the "name clash" (Superclass =? Superclass), but maybe someone has an idea? ...shows a better/n alternative way.

This solution is as easy/complex as "defining SuperclassB and SuperclassC". (questioning the necessity of Superclass!)

Comment: Hello, thank you for taking time. The schema is used to generate code using JAXB, and we need this hierarchy for convenience. When I try adding an override, I get this: "The content of 'schema' is invalid.  Element 'override' is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often.".

Comment: Welcome/my pleasure, @MariaIbragimova. The error message described is typical to XML-Schema v1.0 (, since xs:override was introduced with XML-Schema v1.1) ... which raises a variety of "interesting follow-up questions"...